# Winforms combobox set default selected value not working

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selectedvalue, bunifu

I am using Bunifu UI winforms, I am trying to set the default value for the combobox but my code is not working, I tried setting it with the selectedIndex property but nothing is happening. Can someone help me?
Thanks!

```
ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
        TimeZoneInfo currentTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName);
        Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dic.Add(0, "Choose Timezone");
        foreach (var item in timeZones)
        {
            int time = (item.BaseUtcOffset.Hours * 60 + item.BaseUtcOffset.Minutes) * 60;
            if (!dic.ContainsKey(time))
            {
                dic.Add(time, (time == 0) ? item.DisplayName.Substring(0, 5) : item.DisplayName.Substring(0, 11));
            }
        }

        TimeZoneDropdown.DataSource = dic.ToList();
        TimeZoneDropdown.DisplayMember = "Value";
        TimeZoneDropdown.ValueMember = "Key";
        TimeZoneDropdown.SelectedValue = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Configs.GetValue("TimeZone"))) ? Convert.ToInt32(Configs.GetValue("TimeZone")) : (currentTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset.Hours * 60 + currentTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset.Minutes) * 60;
```

Comment: Where are you running this code? In the Form's Constructor, maybe? Btw, set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` before you set the `DataSource`.

Comment: @Jimi I'm run it in the form constructor, i'm try set DisplayMember, DisplayValue before set DataSource but it not working!

Comment: Keep the sequence (first `DisplayMember` then `DataSource`) and move that code to the `Load` event handler or `OnLoad` method override. See also the notes here: [ComboBox.SelectedValue is null in the Form's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62382640/7444103)

Comment: Thank Jimi, i'm try handler it in form load and it working, but why in form constructor it not work?

Comment: Well, I posted that linked to answer this question exactly. Haven't you read it? The Control has not created its Handle yet, in the Form's Constructor. The Control is not yet *operational*. As described, you can force the Control's Handle creation or subscribe to an event that is raised when all components are already setup, as the `Load` or `Shown` events. Or override  the methods that raise those events (`OnLoad()` and `OnShown()`, or `OnHandleCreated()`, eventually)

Comment: I have read it jimi, but I still don't understand how it happens since the onload event and the constructor are basically the same why he had trouble set SeletectedValue in the constructor. I checked my code and realized that I had reset the value for the combobox in another function causing it to not work.

Comment: The Form's Constructor and its Load event are not by all means the same. The Load event is raised when the Form (and its Controls) are ready to be presented, when the initialization process is complete. After `OnHandleCreated()`

Comment: I agree with your answer. But my point is that it is almost the same in case of set default value for form using Constructor or Formload event, objects after being instantiated can execute without error. In this case set the value for the form in the constructor and the Formload event will be the same!

Comment: Yes, you can *assign* values (the ComboBox is filled - or, it *will* be), but only after the Contructor completes the handles are created, so you can use your Controls. Before that, you cannot (your Controls don't have a Handle yet). So, if you try to set the `SelectedValue`, which doesn't initialize a property, but uses internal functionalities, you're not achieving any *effect*: the Control is not *working* yet.

Comment: This can be tricky to evaluate while debugging, if you're not aware of this. For example, if you sort the ComboBox Items in the Constructor and inspect the collection while debugging, the Items *seem* sorted. They're not: your *inspection* caused the creation of the handle, to allow you to look into a Control's properties, which otherwise wouldn't be available yet. If the creation of the Handle is not forced, the Items are not actually sorted at that point.

Comment: thank Jimi, I will take note of this!