# What is preventing Combobox SelectedValue from setting?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have several comboboxes, all similar code and only one, CustomerSelector.SelectedValue, is not working.  I have even tried setting the value like this: `CustomerSelector.SelectedValue=32`.

This Method is for loading all the Project info to the form and is called in the form Load event.  The data seems to load fine, I have even loaded 'id' to the DisplayMember to verify.

Any ideas what is preventing SelectedValue from setting?

```
        void loadProjectInfo()
        {
            if (isProjectInfoLoaded == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
                    DBConnector db4 = new DBConnector();
                    db4.query = "SELECT * FROM s1_pm_project WHERE id=" + JobID;
                    dt4 = db4.getDataTable();
                    DataRow PMProject = dt4.Rows[0];

                    ProjectNameTextbox.Text = PMProject["ProjectName"].ToString();
                    this.Text = ProjectNameTextbox.Text;

                    ProjectAddressTextbox.Text = PMProject["Address"].ToString();
                    ProjectAddressCity.Text = PMProject["City"].ToString();

                    ProjectAddressState.DataSource = USStates.States();
                    ProjectAddressState.ValueMember = "Abbreviations";
                    ProjectAddressState.DisplayMember = "Abbreviations";
                    ProjectAddressState.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(PMProject["State"]))
                        ProjectAddressState.SelectedValue = PMProject["State"].ToString();
                    ProjectAddressPostalCode.Value = (!Convert.IsDBNull(PMProject["ZipCode"])) ? Convert.ToInt32(PMProject["ZipCode"]) : 00000;

                    DBConnector db5 = new DBConnector();
                    db5.query = "SELECT id, Name FROM s1_customer ORDER BY Name ASC";
                    CustomerSelector.DisplayMember = "Name";
                    CustomerSelector.ValueMember = "id";
                    CustomerSelector.DataSource = db5.getDataTable();
                    CustomerSelector.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    //if (!Convert.IsDBNull(PMProject["CustomerID"]))
                    //    CustomerSelector.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(PMProject["CustomerID"]);
                    CustomerSelector.SelectedValue=32;


                    DBConnector db1 = new DBConnector();
                    db1.query = "SELECT id, description FROM s1_app_status WHERE id < 2";
                    ProjectInfo_Status.DataSource = db1.getDataTable();
                    ProjectInfo_Status.DisplayMember = "description";
                    ProjectInfo_Status.ValueMember = "id";
                    ProjectInfo_Status.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(PMProject["IsActive"]);

                    DBConnector db2 = new DBConnector();
                    db2.query = "SELECT id, description FROM s1_pm_roll";
                    ProjectInfoRollSelector.DataSource = db2.getDataTable();
                    ProjectInfoRollSelector.ValueMember = "id";
                    ProjectInfoRollSelector.DisplayMember = "description";
                    ProjectInfoRollSelector.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(PMProject["RollID"]) > 0)
                        ProjectInfoRollSelector.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(PMProject["RollID"]);

                    DBConnector db3 = new DBConnector();
                    db3.query = "SELECT id, fullname FROM s1_user WHERE id>1";
                    ProjectInfoPMSelector.DataSource = db3.getDataTable();
                    ProjectInfoPMSelector.ValueMember = "id";
                    ProjectInfoPMSelector.DisplayMember = "fullname";
                    ProjectInfoPMSelector.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(PMProject["PMID"]) > 0)
                        ProjectInfoPMSelector.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(PMProject["PMID"]);


                    ProjectInfoJobNoTextbox.Text = PMProject["JobNo"].ToString();
                    ProjectInfoValueTextbox.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(PMProject["ApproxValue"]);
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(PMProject["StartDate"]))
                        StartDateSelector.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(PMProject["StartDate"]);
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(PMProject["ProjectedEndDate"]))
                        ProjectedEndDateSelector.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(PMProject["ProjectedEndDate"]);
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(PMProject["EndDate"]))
                        EndDateSelector.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(PMProject["EndDate"]);
                    CustomerPOTextbox.Text = PMProject["CustomerPO"].ToString();
                    SalesTaxRateTextbox.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(PMProject["SalesTaxRate"]);
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(PMProject["WarrantyBegin"]))
                        WarrantyBegin.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(PMProject["WarrantyBegin"]);
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(PMProject["WarrantyEnd"]))
                        WarrantyEnd.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(PMProject["WarrantyEnd"]);
                    
                    loadContactList();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Errors.Exception(ex);
                }

                isProjectInfoLoaded = true;
            }
        }
```

This is the output from `SELECT id, Name FROM s1_customer ORDER BY Name ASC`:

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 22 | 18-8 Sherman Oaks |
| 206 | Alejo Lugo |
| 233 | Americo Builders, LLC |
| 235 | AMS Solutions, Inc |
| 1 | ARRIS Builders, Inc. |
| 209 | Chris Thrower |
| 105 | CME Refrigeration Controls |
| 53 | Coastline Provisions |
| 117 | Cortech Construction, Inc |
| 6 | Development Support Services, Inc. |
| 146 | East Bay Restaurant Supply Inc |
| 31 | Fitness Mania |
| 7 | Fulcrum Construction |
| 32 | Hardesty & Associates, Inc. |
| 135 | Howards Appliances, Inc. |
| 9 | J Ray Construction |
| 10 | J&L Metal Products |
| 12 | Jahanna L. Nichols Interior Design, Inc |
| 69 | James Barb Construction, Inc |
| 61 | JRE Construction, Inc. |
| 13 | Kamran and Company, Inc. |
| 15 | LA Deli Distributors, Inc. |
| 98 | Lovisa America, LLC |
| 40 | Mobile Customer |
| 120 | N CORONA |
| 180 | N SANTA CLARA |
| 5 | N SERVICE SALE |
| 129 | Orangecrest Properties LLC |
| 223 | Other Customer |
| 78 | Pacific Westline, Inc. |

Output from `SELECT * FROM s1_pm_project WHERE id=`:

| id | ProjectName | IsActive | CustomerID | RollID | PMID | JobNo | ApproxValue | StartDate | EndDate | ProjectedEndDate | CustomerPO | SalesTaxRate | EstimateID | WarrantyBegin | WarrantyEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 141 | Gorjana - Carlsbad | 1 | 32 | 1 | 23 | 22199 | 37000.00 | 2022-02-07 | 2022-04-29 | 2022-04-29 | 22-012-23 | 0.00 | NULL | 2022-04-29 | 2023-04-29 |

Comment: Where / when are you using this code? -- Don't elide the method that contains the code you post. When it's not meaningful by itself, also include the context in which is called.

Comment: If you are not getting any errors and the other combo boxes work successfully, then, are you 100% sure that the values returned from… `Convert.ToInt32(PMProject["CustomerID"])` … are actually valid values that exist in the combo boxes list of items?

Comment: If the value does NOT exist in the combo boxes list of items, then it will simply ignore it and move on, no error will be thrown. The line of code… `CustomerSelector.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(PMProject["CustomerID"]);` … appears to be a good place for a break point so you can check and verify that the returned values are values that actually exist in the combo boxes list of items.

Comment: @JohnG [ComboBox.SelectedValue is null in the Form's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62381280/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi … thanks for the info. I did not know this. However, the posted code does not look like it is in the form’s constructor, agreed a poor assumption on my part, but if it is in the load event or basically “after” the constructor, then shouldn’t the code work? And why do the other combo boxes work?

Comment: @JohnG That's why I asked to clarify in which context this code is called and also *when [the method] is not meaningful by itself, also include the context in which is called*.  I could not get through to the OP, apparently.

Comment: @Jimi … I understand 100%, I have pretty much gone numb on the OP’s clarifying obviously needed info. Obviously, I am making many assumptions, but this is not unusual when the OP leaves out the necessary info as I am sure you already know. But thanks for the info about setting the combos value and the forms constructor, I was not aware of this… So, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Jimi This method is called in the form Load event.

Comment: You don't have to tell me, you have to add the information to the question. -- Anyway, you have `SELECT id, Name FROM s1_customer`, then `CustomerSelector.DisplayMember = "Name"; CustomerSelector.ValueMember = "id";`, so SelectedValue should be set to a value that represents an `id`, but you have `CustomerSelector.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(PMProject["CustomerID"])`: the `CustomerID` field is not in the query and there's no alias, hence it's `null` or it causes an exception.

Comment: @Jimi `PMProject["CustomerID"]` is a field from another query, see above.  To test that this is working, I did `MessageBox.Show(PMProject["CustomerID"].ToString());` and it displays the valid value.  Further, I have tried `CustomerSelector.SelectedValue=32`, and still no success.

Comment: The query is what is set in `db5.query`, I have no idea what `PMProject["CustomerID"]` is, its Type, whether it's a valid selector for what `db5.getDataTable()`, what is the relation between `s1_pm_project` and `s1_customer`, if any, whether the value you're trying to set is actually part what the ComboBox has as its DataSource etc. -- This is a generally very confused setup, there's no surprise it may behave erratically.

Comment: @Jimi I posted the output of the queries, also for testing purposes, i tried to select the value like this `CustomerSelector.SelectedValue=32`, still with no success.

Comment: I have tested your code several times and it works as expected. There must be something else going on. If the combo boxes data source is set as you show with the data that you show… then it SHOULD work. I suggest you create a small [mre] that reproduces the problem. Please [edit] your question and post some code that clearly reproduces the problem you describe. My point is that without a clear example of the problem that we can reproduce… speculation is all you may get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being with the database, specifically the `id` field of `s1_customer`.  For some reason it had the 'unsigned' attribute.  When that was removed, everything worked as expected.